# Most performant way to perform custom one-hot-encoding on a PySpark dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say we have this PySpark dataframe:

```
+----+-------------+
| id | string_data |
+----+-------------+
| 1  | "test"      |
+----+-------------+
| 2  | null        |
+----+-------------+
| 3  | "9"         |
+----+-------------+
| 4  | "deleted__" |
```

I want to perform some operation on this that will result in this dataframe:

```
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| id | string_data | is_string_data_null | is_string_data_a_number | does_string_data_contain_keyword_test | is_string_data_normal |
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| 1  | "test"      | 0                   | 0                       | 1                                     | 0                     |
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| 2  | null        | 1                   | 0                       | 0                                     | 0                     |im
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| 3  | "9"         | 0                   | 1                       | 0                                     | 0                     |
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| 4  | "deleted__" | 0                   | 0                       | 0                                     | 1                     |
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------+-----------------------+
|    |             |                     |                         |                                       |                       |
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

Where each of the new columns has either a 1 or a 0 depending on the truth value. I have currently implemented this using a custom UDF that checks the value of the string_data column, but this is incredibly slow. I have also tried implementing a UDF that does not create new columns but instead overwrites the original one with an encoded vector [1, 0, 0...], etc. This is also too slow because we have to apply this to millions of rows and thousands of columns.

Is there any better way of doing this? I understand UDFs are not the most efficient way to solve things in PySpark but I can't seem to find any built-in PySpark functions that work.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: Sorry, from mobile I didn't see the full expected output so my previous answer was very incomplete.

Anyway, your operation has to be done in two steps, starting with this DataFrame:

```py
>>> df.show()
+---+-----------+
| id|string_data|
+---+-----------+
|  1|       test|
|  2|       null|
|  3|          9|
|  4|  deleted__|
+---+-----------+
```

1. Create the boolean fields based on the conditions in the `string_data` field:

```py
>>> df = (df
    .withColumn('is_string_data_null', df.string_data.isNull())
    .withColumn('is_string_data_a_number', df.string_data.cast('integer').isNotNull())
    .withColumn('does_string_data_contain_keyword_test', coalesce(df.string_data, lit('')).contains('test'))
    .withColumn('is_string_normal', ~(col('is_string_data_null') | col('is_string_data_a_number') | col('does_string_data_contain_keyword_test')))
    )
>>> df.show()
+---+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+----------------+
| id|string_data|is_string_data_null|is_string_data_a_number|does_string_data_contain_keyword_test|is_string_normal|
+---+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+----------------+
|  1|       test|              false|                  false|                                 true|           false|
|  2|       null|               true|                  false|                                false|           false|
|  3|          9|              false|                   true|                                false|           false|
|  4|  deleted__|              false|                  false|                                false|            true|
+---+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+----------------+
```

2. Now that we have our columns, we can cast them to integers:

```py
>>> df = (df
    .withColumn('is_string_data_null', df.is_string_data_null.cast('integer'))
    .withColumn('is_string_data_a_number', df.is_string_data_a_number.cast('integer'))
    .withColumn('does_string_data_contain_keyword_test', df.does_string_data_contain_keyword_test.cast('integer'))
    .withColumn('is_string_normal', df.is_string_normal.cast('integer'))
    )
>>> df.show()
+---+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+----------------+
| id|string_data|is_string_data_null|is_string_data_a_number|does_string_data_contain_keyword_test|is_string_normal|
+---+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+----------------+
|  1|       test|                  0|                      0|                                    1|               0|
|  2|       null|                  1|                      0|                                    0|               0|
|  3|          9|                  0|                      1|                                    0|               0|
|  4|  deleted__|                  0|                      0|                                    0|               1|
+---+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+----------------+
```

This should be far more performant than an UDF, as all the operations are done by Spark itself so there's no context switch from Spark to Python.